# How to make two buttons responsive?

Tags: html, responsive, bootstrap-5

I'm using Bootstrap to make two buttons so that when the screen width decreases, they divide the screen not horizontally, but vertically, something like in the picture
[image]

I tried this

index.php:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md mw-100 bg-danger"></div>
        <div class="col-md mw-100 bg-success"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
[class*='col'] {
    min-height: 600px;
}
```

But it overflows at the bottom when the width is less than 768px and I don't know how to fill the empty space below the buttons when the width is greater than 768px

(sorry for the english, I'm using a translator)

Comment: you don't need any css tags to make it work. see solutions below.

Comment: @L1te please upvote and accept the answer, if it solves your problem, as it will help other people who are facing same issue. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `col-xs-12` and `col-md-6` to get this behaviour.

See results in full page and try to reduce screen size.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class='container-fluid'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-xs-12 col-md-6'>
      <button class='btn btn-primary'>Button 1</button>
     </div>
    <div class='col-xs-12 col-md-6'>
      <button class='btn btn-danger'>Button 2</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing your col divs. try this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md">
            <button class="btn btn-danger"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md">
            <button class="btn btn-success"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```